# ASP.NET CORE MVC: `asp-action` doesn't create the `href` attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Visual Studio 2017 (v15.4.4)
ASP.NET CORE MVC

Code source:

```
@model Razor.Models.GuestResponse
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @ViewBag.Greeting World (from the view)
    <p>We're going to have an excuting party.<br/>
    (To do: sell it better. Add pictures or something.)</p>
    <a asp-action="RsvpForm">RSVP Now.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But `asp-action` attribute doesn't create the `href` attribute. I get such result in Google Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/50E639F5-BFDC-EB4A-B0CB-8404EE08E366/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script><link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/663E80EE4048-BC0B-A4BE-CDFB-5F936E05/abn/main.css"/></head>
<body>
    Good Afternoon World (from the view)
    <p>We're going to have an excuting party.<br/>
    (To do: sell it better. Add pictures or something.)</p>
    <a asp-action="RsvpForm">RSVP Now.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

What can be the reason for such result?

Comment: Is this code inside a razor view ? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: In my case, the lack of these two lines caused that three effects:
1) no href inside links (looks like a link but the mouse cursor is text) 
2) no labels were displayed above the input fields
3) no data was shown in them... 
Thnx a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use these two lines of code above your View :

```
@model Razor.Models.GuestResponse

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, YourProjetcName
```

If the problem did not resolve after adding these codes restart visual studio.

Comment: Thank you. It fixed my problem. It is strange that these important code rows are absent in the code example of the book that I read.

Comment: @AndreyBushman If your problem is resolved please mark to use the rest

Comment: Yes, of course. But this site requires to me waiting some minutes before I do it.

Comment: Use `_ViewImports` file with following codes in View folder help me